# Use getattr from a Mixin class that lives in a different module to get a class from the caller

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Mixin class the lives in myModule.mixins. A new class in myModule.main (MyPaternalClass) is inheriting from myModule.mixins.MyMixin.

The purpose of this mixin is to generate new "child" objects given a string with the name of the child class, but the classes for these objects live in myModule.main, not in myModule.mixins

I understand how to do this when the Mixin lives in the same module using:

```
this = sys.modules[__name__]
cls = getattr(this, objType)
new_cls_inst = cls()
```

However I'm having trouble finding a good way to do this when the mixin class lives in its own module.

ex. myModule.mixins

```
class MyMixin(object):
  def new_obj(self, objType):
    cls = #Get the class
    newobj = cls()
    return newobj
```

Now, this mixin would be used in the following:

ex. myModule.main

```
from .mixin import MyMixin
class MyPaternalClass(MyMixin):
  def __init__(self):
     super(MyPaternalClass, self).__init__()
     self.children = []

  def add_child(self, child_type):
    self.children.append(self.new_obj(child_type))

class Son(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class Daughter(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

The usage would look similar to this:

```
new_parent = MyPaternalClass()
new_parent.add_child('Son')
new_parent.add_child('Daughter')
```

The reason the mixin class can't live in the same module is because it's intended to be used generically in several other modules.

Comment: Why not have `add_child` take the actual class instead of the class name?

Comment: Well, I had to abstract the example due to the proprietary nature of the source, but basically it calling this function when it's Decoding data from a json file. 

The JSON file stores the class name of the children, so it needs to be able to repopulate an empty class with new children using the string. 

In my case, however, it can be safely assumed that the new_obj it's creating will live in myModule.main or myModule.other or wherever it's being called from. It will just never be in myModule.mixin